# method call between different class in Objective c

Tags: objective-c, methods

Is it possible to call method from one class to another 
where two classes from two different parent class. Suppose one from
UIImage class and another from UIViewController class?

Comment: Please clarify your question a bit. Are you just asking how to invoke an instance's methods?

Comment: I know the answer is yes, I just do not understand the question. Please provide a more fleshed out example, are you hinting of multiple inheritance?

Comment: Yes,i m asking about instance method.plz someone give me some explanation with example.

Comment: Uhhmmm you do `[object method:argument]`, tweak this example to suit the actual method you intent to call.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, one of the cool things about Objective-C is that you can call a method on any object, even if it doesn't respond.  Although not as robust as in Objective-C's father, SmallTalk (yes, SmallTalk is the dad and C is the mom, don't ask), it's still pretty powerful.  So let's say you have something like this:

```
- (void)doSomethingToThis: (id)thisObject
{
  [thisObject doSomething];
}
```

Then later...

```
//...
  UIImage *thisImage = ...
  UIViewController *thisController = ...

  [self doSomethingToThis: thisImage];
  [self doSomethingToThis: thisController];
//...
```

Something like this will compile just fine, but be warned if `UIImage` and `UIViewController` don't both respond to `doSomething`, then you could end up with a crasher (depends on how you have the compiler flags set, but I believe by default you'll get a crash).

Comment: Nice answer, but I am not sure it is the correct answer for the question. Heck, I have no clue what the question is.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to do something like what is said in this answer of another question:

[Objective-C : Call a method from another class in addTarget:action:forControlEvents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3944231/objective-c-call-a-method-from-another-class-in-addtargetactionforcontroleven/3944299#3944299)