# Objective-C : Call a method from another class in addTarget:action:forControlEvents

Tags: iphone, objective-c, events, uibutton

Here is my problem :

I want to assign an Event on an UIButton. I use this method :

```
- (void)addTarget:(id)target
action:(SEL)action
forControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)controlEvents
```

like this :

```
[newsButton addTarget:self
action:@selector(myEvent2)
forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

newsButton is my UIButton.

If myEvent2 belongs to the class where I am, the code is compiling and executing fine, everybody is happy.

But if myEvent2 belongs to another class I don't succeed to execute it (the project compiles fine).

I tried out to change my code in that way :

```
MyViewController* test = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
[newsButton addTarget:self
action:@selector([test myEvent2])
forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

but I get the followings errors :

> Expected ':' before '[' token
>
> Method name missing in @selector

Does someone have any solution to my problem ?

Thanks by advance :)

Answer (score 8):

You need to change `addTarget:self` to `addTarget:test`

Comment: When I changed the target from self to :test the complier didn't recognize it since it wasn't an object. The target needs to be an object and test appears to be a class.

Answer (score 4):

```
MyViewController* test = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
[newsButton addTarget:test
    action:@selector(myEvent2)
    forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use a redirection method:

```
- (void)myRedirectHandler {
    [ test myEvent2 ];
}
```

...

```
[newsButton addTarget:self
    action:@selector(myRedirectHandler)
    forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```