# Calling methods in different classes

Tags: class, methods, cocos2d-iphone, move

This question is semi-similar to the one [asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1496281/method-call-between-different-class-in-objective-c)

But the difference is that I'm using cocos2d.
I have a method named screenshot in my AppDelegate. It's obviously used to take a screenshot. I want to call this method in another class, but simply doing [self screenshot]; isn't working out because I get the warning 'GameOver' my not respond to '-screenshot'.

All I want is for the screenshot method to be called in GameOver.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't call a method that does not exists - it will generate a runtime error.

If you want to call a method of AppDelegate from GameOver you should have a pointer to AppDelegate object if the method is not static:

```
[appDelegatePointer screenshot];
```

If the method is static

```
[AppDelegate screenshot];
```

I suppose you have only one object AppDelegate and you can make a static method

```
+(AppDelegate) sharedDelegate;
```

of class AppDelegate that will return your object singleton. And so you will be able to call `screenshot` method from GameOver object or from any other place like this:

```
[[AppDelegate sharedDelegate] screenshot];
```

Such thing is done in CCDirector, CCTextureCache, SimpleAudioEngine, ... classes in Cocos2D